# Creating A Login For My Website

Tags: sql, database, web, authentication

I am looking into creating a login for my website. I am currently receiving free hosting from my college (UW Whitewater) server. I have learned HTML, CSS and JavaScript fairly well, but have not used any of these three languages a ton.

I would like to create a login for users to login to see their account information and use a web app that I will be creating in the future, but for now that doesn't matter.

I would like to know an overhead view of what I need to be able to have a login and keep account information for users.

Now I'm guessing I'm gonna need a database, and some kind of PHP or server-side language. Which language will be the best? As for the database is it possible to use an Access database? Also I dont know if UW Whitewater has mySQL that I can use or not? Is that possible? I would like to keep this free... college student here haha. I would also definitely be willing to learn a new language too.

Thanks for any replies in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, here's what I would do:

1. Decide what server-side language you want to use and which database you want to use based on whatever is available at your college. Although it is possible that they support many languages, if you ask the local IT administrators they will probably be able to suggest the best one for you, or they might even have a standard that they mandate.
2. Once you know which server-side language and database, do a web search on how to create a simple user login page with that language and database. There are tons out there.

If you run into any *specific* problems with your chosen solution, this would be the place to post them. But your question at the moment is probably a bit too broad.

Comment: okay sounds good. thank you!   EDIT: is there any way to tell which they support by their server? or will I have to ask them (their not available today)

Comment: Hmmm... how are you accessing the server at the moment? If you are using SSH, then you can try typing `php -v` and if you PHP is installed, that will tell you what version. If PHP is installed, there is a good chance MySQL and/or SQLite will also be installed. If you are accessing via some kind of web-based self-service app (like with regular shared hosting), then look for language and database options within that. You could also use `netcraft.com` to check the IP address of one of the servers or the host name of a site that is hosted on one of the servers and it will tell you what is running.

Comment: well according to: students.uww.edu/webstoragedocs/hints-students.html they have PHP. They encourage FTP as the main access type. Is there a way to check through FTP? Im gonna see if i can connect via ssh I dont see PHP or SQL on the report here: http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.uww.edu